# CoreNLP Stanford Dependency Format

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

> Bills on ports and immigration were submitted by Senator Brownback,
>   Republican of Kansas

From the above sentence, I am looking to obtain the following typed dependencies:

```
nsubjpass(submitted, Bills)
auxpass(submitted, were)
agent(submitted, Brownback)
nn(Brownback, Senator)
appos(Brownback, Republican)
prep_of(Republican, Kansas)
prep_on(Bills, ports)
conj_and(ports, immigration)
prep_on(Bills, immigration)
```

This *should be possible* as per Table 1, Figure 1 on the documentation for [Stanford Dependencies](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-dependencies.shtml).

Using the below code I have only been able to achieve the following dependency makeup (code outputs this):

```
root(ROOT-0, submitted-7)
nmod:on(Bills-1, ports-3)
nmod:on(Bills-1, immigration-5)
case(ports-3, on-2)
cc(ports-3, and-4)
conj:and(ports-3, immigration-5)
nsubjpass(submitted-7, Bills-1)
auxpass(submitted-7, were-6)
nmod:agent(submitted-7, Brownback-10)
case(Brownback-10, by-8)
compound(Brownback-10, Senator-9)
punct(Brownback-10, ,-11)
appos(Brownback-10, Republican-12)
nmod:of(Republican-12, Kansas-14)
case(Kansas-14, of-13)
```

**Question** - How do I achieve the desired output above?

**Code**

```
public void processTestCoreNLP() {
    String text = "Bills on ports and immigration were submitted " +
            "by Senator Brownback, Republican of Kansas";

    Annotation annotation = new Annotation(text);
    Properties properties = PropertiesUtils.asProperties(
            "annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,depparse"
    );

    AnnotationPipeline pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(properties);

    pipeline.annotate(annotation);

    for (CoreMap sentence : annotation.get(SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
        SemanticGraph sg = sentence.get(EnhancedPlusPlusDependenciesAnnotation.class);
        Collection<TypedDependency> dependencies = sg.typedDependencies();
        for (TypedDependency td : dependencies) {
            System.out.println(td);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the code actually print out, then?

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguity. The code outputs the second block of dependencies. I have edited to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the CCprocessed and collapsed Stanford Dependencies (SD) for a sentence through the NN dependency parser, you'll have to set a property to circumvent a small bug in CoreNLP.

**However**, please note that we are **no longer maintaining the Stanford Dependencies code** and unless you have really good reasons to use SD, we'd recommend using Universal Dependencies for any new projects. Take a look at the [Universal Dependencies (UD) documentation](http://www.universaldependencies.org) and [Schuster and Manning (2016)](https://nlp.stanford.edu/~sebschu/pubs/schuster-manning-lrec2016.pdf) for more information on the UD representation.

To obtain the CCprocessed and collapsed SD representation, set the `depparse.language` property as follows:

```
public void processTestCoreNLP() {
  String text = "Bills on ports and immigration were submitted " +
        "by Senator Brownback, Republican of Kansas";

  Annotation annotation = new Annotation(text);
  Properties properties = PropertiesUtils.asProperties(
        "annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,depparse");

  properties.setProperty("depparse.language", "English")

  AnnotationPipeline pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(properties);

  pipeline.annotate(annotation);

  for (CoreMap sentence : annotation.get(SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
    SemanticGraph sg = sentence.get(CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation.class);
    Collection<TypedDependency> dependencies = sg.typedDependencies();
    for (TypedDependency td : dependencies) {
      System.out.println(td);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sebastien. This is what I had been looking for all along. I even searched the mailers but didn't come across this one.

Comment: Is the quality of english_SD and english _UD the same? The file sizes are very different and the dependency graph arrows are very different

Answer (score 2):

CoreNLP recently switched from the old [Stanford dependencies](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-dependencies.shtml) format (the format in the top example) to [Universal Dependencies](http://universaldependencies.org/). My first recommendation is to use the new format if at all possible. Continuing development on the parsers will be using universal dependencies, and the format is in many ways similar to the old format, modulo cosmetic changes (e.g., `prep` -> `nmod`).

However, if you'd like to get the old dependency format out, you can do so with the `CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation` annotation.

Comment: thank you for this answer. Through my investigation this is what I thought to be true but upon using the `CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation` I still receive the same universal style dependencies i.e. `nmod` still appears when it should be `prep`. Is there anyway to force a regression back to `prep`?

Comment: I went a bit further and managed to have it output `prep` rather than `nmod`. What I notice now though is that they have not been reduced to `prep_on`. Instead I have 2 separate dependencies `prep(Bills, on)` and `pobj(on, immigration)`. How do I reduce this to `prep_on(Bills, immigration)`. Do I have to do it myself or is there a method?

Comment: I'm getting out of my depth here, but the place to start spelunking would be `GrammaticalStructure`. There is, however, a chance that the Stanford Dependencies representation has been deprecated for long enough now that it's started to bit rot (e.g., `CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation` is certainly meant to return the old format).

Comment: No, we always just produce either Universal Dependencies or Stanford Dependencies and `CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation` also contains a post-processed version of Universal Dependencies if you don't tell CoreNLP to generate SD by using one of the options described on https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-dependencies.shtml.

Comment: But I'd also recommend using Universal Dependencies through the `EnhancedPlusPlusDependenciesAnnotation`, which will turn prepositional phrases into things like `nmod:on` in cases where SD output `prep_on`. (So the primary change is that the main relation is called `nmod` instead of `prep` and that the separator is a colon instead of an underscore.)

Comment: And there is also a bug if you use the NN dependency parser with SD, which might be the reason why you don't get the right dependencies. See this thread for how to circumvent this bug: https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/parser-user/2016-March/003278.html

Comment: @SebastianSchuster that bug was the reason for all my issues! Thank you for that. Would you mind rewriting that as an answer and I can award you the bounty?