# What's the tags meaning of Stanford dependency parser(3.9.1)?

Tags: nltk, stanford-nlp

I used the Stanford dependency parser(3.9.1) to parse a sentence, and I got the result as the following.

```
    [[(('investigating', 'VBG'), 'nmod', ('years', 'NNS')),
  (('years', 'NNS'), 'case', ('In', 'IN')),
  (('years', 'NNS'), 'det', ('the', 'DT')),
  (('years', 'NNS'), 'amod', ('last', 'JJ')),
  (('years', 'NNS'), 'nmod', ('century', 'NN')),
  (('century', 'NN'), 'case', ('of', 'IN')),
  (('century', 'NN'), 'det', ('the', 'DT')),
  (('century', 'NN'), 'amod', ('nineteenth', 'JJ')),
  (('investigating', 'VBG'), 'nsubj', ('Planck', 'NNP')),
  (('investigating', 'VBG'), 'aux', ('was', 'VBD')),
  (('investigating', 'VBG'), 'dobj', ('problem', 'NN')),
  (('problem', 'NN'), 'det', ('the', 'DT')),
  (('problem', 'NN'), 'nmod', ('radiation', 'NN')),
  (('radiation', 'NN'), 'case', ('of', 'IN')),
  (('radiation', 'NN'), 'amod', ('black-body', 'JJ')),
  (('radiation', 'NN'), 'acl', ('posed', 'VBN')),
  (('posed', 'VBN'), 'advmod', ('first', 'RB')),
  (('posed', 'VBN'), 'nmod', ('Kirchhoff', 'NNP')),
  (('Kirchhoff', 'NNP'), 'case', ('by', 'IN')),
  (('Kirchhoff', 'NNP'), 'advmod', ('earlier', 'RBR')),
  (('earlier', 'RBR'), 'nmod:npmod', ('years', 'NNS')),
  (('years', 'NNS'), 'det', ('some', 'DT')),
  (('years', 'NNS'), 'amod', ('forty', 'JJ'))]]
```

Some of the tags meaning such as 'nmod' and 'acl' are missing in the [StanfordDependencyManual](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf).The newest manual version I can find is 3.7.0. I also find some explanation at a [Standard_list_of_dependency_relations](https://wiki.opencog.org/w/Dependency_relations#Standard_list_of_dependency_relations)
But it still missed some tags.

Hence, my question is where can I find the newest version of the explanation of these tags? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the last few versions, the Stanford parser has been generating [Universal Dependencies](http://universaldependencies.org/) rather than Stanford Dependencies. The new relation set can be found [here](http://universaldependencies.org/docsv1/en/dep/index.html), and are listed below (for version 1 -- version 2 seems to be a work-in-progress still?):

```
acl: clausal modifier of noun
acl:relcl: relative clause modifier
advcl: adverbial clause modifier
advmod: adverbial modifier
amod: adjectival modifier
appos: appositional modifier
aux: auxiliary
auxpass: passive auxiliary
case: case marking
cc: coordination
cc:preconj: preconjunct
ccomp: clausal complement
compound: compound
compound:prt: phrasal verb particle
conj: conjunct
cop: copula
csubj: clausal subject
csubjpass: clausal passive subject
dep: dependent
det: determiner
det:predet: predeterminer
discourse: discourse element
dislocated: dislocated elements
dobj: direct object
expl: expletive
foreign: foreign words
goeswith: goes with
iobj: indirect object
list: list
mark: marker
mwe: multi-word expression
name: name
neg: negation modifier
nmod: nominal modifier
nmod:npmod: noun phrase as adverbial modifier
nmod:poss: possessive nominal modifier
nmod:tmod: temporal modifier
nsubj: nominal subject
nsubjpass: passive nominal subject
nummod: numeric modifier
parataxis: parataxis
punct: punctuation
remnant: remnant in ellipsis
reparandum: overridden disfluency
root: root
vocative: vocative
xcomp: open clausal complement
```

Although no longer maintained, you can get the old dependency format by setting the property `depparse.language` to `English` (see, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45202486/corenlp-stanford-dependency-format)):

```
properties.setProperty("depparse.language", "English")
```